# block execution iOS and assigning variable

Tags: ios, objective-c-blocks

I am using the drupal-ios-sdk (based on AFNetworking) and my app has a Tab Bar Controller created with storyboard. When loading one of the view controllers I am creating a request in `initWithCoder` with drupal-ios-sdk and assigning an instance variable in the `success block`. Later in `viewDidLoad` I try to print this variable and I'm interested in why I have to retain the instance variable in the success block, even if I define the variable with autorelease.

This is not ARC!

## Not using retain in the success block

### My VC.h

```
@interface AboutViewController : UIViewController {
    @private
    NSDictionary *response;
    NSString *aboutPageHTML;

}
@end
```

### My VC.m

```
-(id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
if ((self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])) {
    NSDictionary *viewData = [NSMutableDictionary new];

    [viewData setValue:@"aboutse" forKey:@"view_name"];

    aboutPageHTML = [[[NSString alloc]init] autorelease];

    void(^successBlock)(AFHTTPRequestOperation*, id) =
    ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        response = [responseObject copy];
        aboutPageHTML = [response valueForKey:@"body"];
        NSLog(@"%s - %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, aboutPageHTML);

        [aboutPageHTML retain]; // critical!

    };

    [DIOSView viewGet:viewData success:successBlock
              failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                  NSLog(@"%s, %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, error);            
    }];

}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    NSLog(@"%s - %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, aboutPageHTML);
    NSLog(@"%s - %f %f", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height);  
}
```

### Edit:

declaring the variable with `__block` does not seem to make a difference. How come?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many things wrong with this code. `aboutPageHTML` is an instance variable that you want a strong reference to (i.e. should be retained). In `aboutPageHTML = [[[NSString alloc]init] autorelease];` you are not maintaining a strong reference to it. This is incorrect.

And later on, in your success block (it is irrelevant that it is a block; it's just any code that runs later), you do `aboutPageHTML = [response valueForKey:@"body"]; [aboutPageHTML retain];` which does retain the object stored in that instance variable. So you are being inconsistent with the memory management for the same instance variable in two places.

Also, when you assign another value to a strongly-referenced variable, you should make sure to release the previous value, which you are not doing. This goes for both `aboutPageHTML` and `response`.

Finally, the object pointed to by `viewData` is leaked, as you have a strong reference to it (you use `new`) but don't release it.

Also, you should use `setObject:forKey:` and `objectForKey:` for dictionaries. And you need to declare a mutable dictionary when you want a dictionary you can change. (This is probably why you (incorrectly) decided to use `setValue:forKey:`)

So in conclusion, this would be more like it:

```
-(id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
if ((self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])) {
    NSMutableDictionary *viewData = [NSMutableDictionary new];

    [viewData setObject:@"aboutse" forKey:@"view_name"];

    aboutPageHTML = [[NSString alloc] init];

    void(^successBlock)(AFHTTPRequestOperation*, id) =
    ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        [response release];
        response = [responseObject copy];
        [aboutPageHTML release];
        aboutPageHTML = [[response objectForKey:@"body"] retain];
    };

    [DIOSView viewGet:viewData success:successBlock
              failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                  NSLog(@"%s, %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, error);            
    }];
    [viewData release];
}
return self;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you mean that autorelease will impose a weak reference? Edit: how come I don't need to declare aboutPageHTML with __block identifier? Regarding the dictionary, how come such a method exists for a regular dictionary (setValue:forKey:)?

Comment: @hajder: `__block` is only needed if you need to assign to the variable (or to keep the block from retaining the variable in MRC). You don't need to do anything like that here. `setValue:forKey:` is part of Key-Value Coding, which applies generally to all objects. You don't want to use KVC here.

Comment: sorry, but isn't  aboutPageHTML = [[response objectForKey:@"body"] retain]; an assignment ? Also do you mean that autorelease (non-ARC) will create a weak reference?

Comment: @hajder: autorelease, like release, means you are giving up ownership of it. I don't understand what you're saying about the assignment.

Comment: you wrote "__block is only needed if you need to assign to the variable ". Now isn't the line aboutPageHTML = [[response objectForKey:@"body"] retain] an assignment? And if so, why don't we need the __block identifier for aboutPageHTML?

Comment: @hajder: I should be more specific. `__block` only applies to local variables. `aboutPageHTML` is an instance variable, not a local variable. Instance variables are not not captured by blocks. Rather, `self` is captured (`self` *is* a local variable) and instance variables are accessed through `self`.