# iOS - How to control block execution order when the block always get data after assigning variables?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, afnetworking, block

I'm new to iOS programming and I'm pretty sure many others have faced the same issue.

The thing is, I use `AFNetworking` to handle my http requests.

I'm trying to get some data in my `init` method and I want to assign a variable with those data in `ViewDidLoad()`.

It seems that `AFNetworking` send a `get` request with a block**(maybe an asynchronous one but I haven't learnt about threads yet)**.

And when I'm assigning, the data which I'm trying to get has yet returned.

I've googled for answers like

[The execution of block is always delayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9478456/the-execution-of-block-is-always-delayed)

[block execution iOS and assigning variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15540348/block-execution-ios-and-assigning-variable)

[Variable returning null after block execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13350108/variable-returning-null-after-block-execution)

but found no solution.

**I wonder whether this is because of the multi-thread mechanism and how can I solve the problem?**

---

## CODE

**HomeController.m**

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSInteger cateid = indexPath.row + 1;
    HomeTabCategoryController* categoryController = [[HomeTabCategoryController alloc] initWithCategoryId:cateid andCategoryName:[_categories objectForKey: [@(indexPath.row + 1) stringValue]]];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:categoryController animated:YES];
}
```

**CategoryController.m**

```
-(instancetype)initWithCategoryId:(NSInteger)categoryId andCategoryName:(NSString*)categoryName{
    self = [super init];
    if (!self) {
        return nil;
    }
[ProductModel getProductsIdOfCategory:_categoryId success:^(BOOL result, NSString* message, NSArray* productIds){
        if (!result) {
            _productIds = productIds;
        }else{
            [self toast:message];
        }
    }failure:^(NSError* error){
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    }];
    return self;
}

-(void)viewDidLoad{
    NSLog(@"loading view");
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = _categoryName;

    [self getData];
}

- (void)getData{

for (NSNumber* proId in _productIds) {
    [ProductModel getProductWithId:[proId integerValue] success:^(BOOL result, NSString* message, ProductEntity* product){
        if (!result) {
            [_products addObject:product];
        }else{
            [self toast:message];
        }
    }failure:^(NSError* error){
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    }];
}
}
```

When `getData` is executed, `_productIds` is still `nil`(I assign it in `success` block).

Comment: Can you share few more details. 
Why you need to call on INIT ?
I believe this can be achieved with GCD serial queue.

Comment: It is because I have a `UITableView` in `HomeController` and when I select a certain row I want to show a new view. Actually I've never learned about `GCD` before. If it is the problem with `GCD` I'll definitely go get some document myself and learn to use it. But the problem is, I don't even no what exactly the problem is (I mean I want more detail about how does thing work in my code). Could you please give some advice? Is there a thread created in the block? When does the block actually executed? Thank in advance. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can't you call you init method like i-e call when you have response (productIds) & it make sense.

```
> -(instancetype)initWithCategoryId:(NSInteger)categoryId andCategoryName:(NSString*)categoryName{
>     self = [super init];
>     if (!self) {
>         return nil;
>     } [ProductModel getProductsIdOfCategory:_categoryId success:^(BOOL result, NSString* message, NSArray* productIds){
>         if (!result) {
>             _productIds = productIds;
             **[self getData];**
>         }else{
>             [self toast:message];
>         }
>     }failure:^(NSError* error){
>         NSLog(@"%@", error);
>     }];
>     return self; }
```

Comment: Yes it works. But I still don't understand things inside and this may lead to the same problem in the future. Could you please just give a hint? I'll google for details myself. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Kindly accept the answer. If it worked for you & solves the problem so that visitors could take benefit.

Comment: Nops it will not. Reason is, you are now calling method which is using that ARRAY only when that ARRAY is filled. Thats how it should be. 

Block are like ASYNC call. Completion will get called only when you receive response. Only reason that array was empty is, ViewDidLoad was getting called before block-response.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want it like, once I get response from API call only than call another API or method. Than use GCD serial queue like below

```
> dispatch_queue_t serialQueue =
> dispatch_queue_create("com.xyzapp.queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
>     
>     dispatch_async(serialQueue, ^{
> 
> [ProductModel getProductsIdOfCategory:_categoryId success:^(BOOL
> result, NSString* message, NSArray* productIds){
>         if (!result) {
>             _productIds = productIds;
>         }else{
>             [self toast:message];
>         }
>     }failure:^(NSError* error){
>         NSLog(@"%@", error);
>     }];
> 
>     });
>     
>     dispatch_async(serialQueue, ^{
>         
>         [self getData];
>     });
```